# How to convert to NumPy datetime while downloading from Big Query

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am downloading the results of a query into a dataframe with this:

```
results = pandas.read_gbq(query=date_query, credentials=sa_creds)
```

The results of the query if saved as table in BQ would have the following schema:

```
my_date     DATE        NULLABLE
my_time     TIME        NULLABLE    
r_field1    INTEGER     NULLABLE    
r_field2    STRING      NULLABLE    
r_field3    FLOAT       NULLABLE    
r_field4    FLOAT       NULLABLE
```

The error that I get when I try to save into results from the solo line above is the following:

```
ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime
```

From my search I suspect that it can't save `my_time` as a `NumPy datetime` object although the error doesn't specify the field. I just thought that the other one is `date` so it shouldn't have an issue.

Is there a workaround for this that doesn't involve me changing the query/schema?

Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of you code? How you save it in BQ for example

Comment: To get the schema above I just ran the query from the Web GUI and saved it the results as table. I am not doing it via python yet. Later on I will use `.to_gbq` to save it via python. The line I shared is the only relevant line. The rest of the script is irrelevant.

Comment: But which command generated the error?

Comment: `results = pandas.read_gbq(query=date_query, credentials=sa_creds)`

Comment: Can you try running pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery pyarrow and then run it again?

Comment: @rmesteves that did it for me. If there's more to form an explanation write it down as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Great, Ill do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this problem basically because your environment is using old versions of some libraries. 
This migration [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration) use as example some codes that query public data from `BigQuery`, including tables with TIME type.

After reproducing the same problem in my environment and comparing my libraries versions to this tutorial's libraries versions, I realized that google-cloud-bigquery and pyarrow libraries were not up to date.

As was discussed in the comments, to solve the problem you have to run:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery pyarrow
```